# pca- valueError: could not convert string to float: 'finalized'

Tags: python, pca

When I'm trying to do pca on my data I get this error.
If my data contains string, pca can not be performed ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUnFz.png)

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from tabulate import tabulate
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from tabulate import tabulate



#perform pca
#pca = PCA(0.9).fit(X)
pca = PCA(0.8)
pca.fit(X) 
X_pca = pca.transform(X)

[enter image description here][2]
```

Comment: PCA cant be used with categorical variables aka string cuz its compute some linear transformation to the input

Answer (score 0):

PCA works by multiplying your data by their n-highest **principal components**, ie their eigenvectors with the n-highest eigenvalues. It is not meaningful to talk about the eigenvectors of non-numerical data. You should convert strings to an appropriate numerical representation before performing PCA.